# spring scoped proxy bean

Tags: java, spring, proxy

Can someone explain the usage of the spring `@ScopedProxy` annotation? I *thought* it had something to do with session scoped beans, but I'm not quite sure what.

In my usage of scopes, I've used session scoped beans without the `@ScopedProxy` annotation (or without aop scoped proxies), so I'm really sure how to use it properly.

Comment: check out [the bean documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html).  Session is [one of the scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection), but not the only one.

Comment: @Gus, I'm aware of the scopes, just not sure how scoped proxy plays into that

Comment: [Section 3.4.4.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) is in my opinion is a pretty good explanation of what a scoped proxy does. -- the bit in between the two examples is the important part.

Comment: Yeah that explains it, thanks. If you want to add an answer to the question I'll accept.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

[Section 3.4.4.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) of the spring docs explains it pretty well:

(please note that the following 'userPreferences' bean definition as it stands is incomplete):

```
<!-- an HTTP Session-scoped bean -->
<bean id="userPreferences" class="com.foo.UserPreferences" scope="session"/>

<!-- a singleton-scoped bean -->
<bean id="userManager" class="com.foo.UserManager">
    <property name="userPreferences" ref="userPreferences"/>
</bean>
```

From the above configuration it is evident that the singleton bean 'userManager' is being injected with a reference to the HTTP Session-scoped bean 'userPreferences'. The salient point here is that the ***'userManager' bean is a singleton***... it will be ***instantiated exactly once per container***, ***and its dependencies*** (in this case only one, the 'userPreferences' bean) ***will also only be injected (once!)***.

This means that the 'userManager' will (conceptually) only ever operate on the exact same 'userPreferences' object, that is the one that it was originally injected with.

This is not what you want when you inject a HTTP Session-scoped bean as a dependency into a collaborating object (typically). Rather, ***what we do want is a single 'userManager' object per container***, and then, ***for the lifetime of a HTTP Session, we want to see and use a 'userPreferences' object that is specific to said HTTP Session***.

Rather what you need then is to inject some sort of object that exposes the exact same public interface as the UserPreferences class (ideally an object that is a UserPreferences instance) and that is smart enough to be able to go off and fetch the real UserPreferences object from whatever underlying scoping mechanism we have chosen (HTTP request, Session, etc.). We can then safely inject this proxy object into the 'userManager' bean, which will be blissfully unaware that the UserPreferences reference that it is holding onto is a ***proxy***.

In our case, ***when a UserManager instance invokes a method on the dependency-injected UserPreferences object, it will really be invoking a method on the proxy***... the proxy will then go off and fetch the real UserPreferences object from (in this case) the HTTP Session, and delegate the method invocation onto the retrieved real UserPreferences object.

That is why you need the following, correct and complete, configuration when injecting request-, session-, and globalSession-scoped beans into collaborating objects:

```
<bean id="userPreferences" class="com.foo.UserPreferences" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>

<bean id="userManager" class="com.foo.UserManager">
    <property name="userPreferences" ref="userPreferences"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: So when I use the @ScopedProxy annotation, a Proxy will be automatically used, and this is all? ScopedProxy means -> Do not use this class as it is, use a Proxy for it?

Comment: I am using spring-web:4.3.3 and it looks like the annotation `@ScopedProxy` was replaced with `@RequestScope` and others. You can find examples here: http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/scoped-proxy/

Comment: We could say when notation `@Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` is used, SpringMVC does not use WebApplicationContext for Autowired, instead it use CGLIB for create the proxy?. Here other explanation with examples [out](http://tuhrig.de/making-a-spring-bean-session-scoped/)

Comment: Can the same be achieved using ApplicationContextAware interface or Method Injection?

Answer (score 0):

After trying out various different options specified here and spring documentation, i have figured out for some reason Spring MVC, is wierdly autowiring controller when you use @Controller annotation and where you have more than one such controller in your webapp. Modified the annotation to @RestController (value="UniqueControllerv1"), the issue is resolved.