# Session scoped Mbean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, web

I am using following code to register the Mbean in a Spring MVC application.

```
@ManagedResource(objectName = "spring:name=TestService", description = "Test Mbean")
```

and `@ManagedAttribute`

This works for singleton and prototype based scope types. For session and request based scope types I receive the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter' defined in class org.springframework.context.annotation.MBeanExportConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.calculatorService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410) ~[spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.calculatorService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:344) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.autodetect(MBeanExporter.java:880) ~[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.autodetectBeans(MBeanExporter.java:842) ~[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:521) ~[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterPropertiesSet(MBeanExporter.java:413) ~[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:90) ~[spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:330) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Is it it possible to create session/request scoped Mbeans?
If so, does anyone has any suggestions?

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
 @Scope(value="session")  --> produces the error

 @Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`) --> Works!

 @Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
 @ManagedResource(objectName = "spring:name=testService", description =   "test Mbean") --> produces the same error again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the exception already tells you the solution for your proplem

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.calculatorService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;`

The point is, that you try to reference a session/request scoped bean from a singleton scoped bean. During application start there isn't any Session or Request active in your app. Therefore the scoped beans aren't instantiated.

By defining a Proxy you can solve this issue.

Actually I think this issue is an duplicate of [spring scoped proxy bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371335/spring-scoped-proxy-bean)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I edited the question. I works with a proxy without the @ManagedResource. If i add it, same error.

Comment: Why do you want to inject a managed resource into your session scoped bean? Why don't you abstract this with a service layer?